# WPF Child window not opening windowstate Normal

Tags: c#, wpf, window, system-tray

I have a WPF program that I want to be minimized most of the time to the system tray..

However when it is minimized to the system tray, the child Windows that open when a message is received does not open in normal window state but opens minimized in the system tray..

I have tried

```
msgWindow.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
msgWindow.Show();
```

But this does not work.. I can fix it by doing

```
this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
msgWindow.Show();
```

However I do not want the main window to be opened every time a message pops up..

Answer (score 0):

Please try this it will help you.

```
Window2 win2 = new Window2();//here i established the child window named as Window2
win2.Show();
```

The above code diplay both window(main and child) concurrently.

```
 Window2 win2 = new Window2();//here i established the child window named as Window2
 win2.Show();
 this.Close();
```

The above code diplay child window only.